# Upload multiple files via CURL

Tags: bash, curl, travis-ci

I'd like to automate my deployment process (using TravisCI) by uploading the built artifacts to my server, which automatically registers these uploads and moves them where they need to go.

For this I've written a shellscript that's executed after the build process succeeded:

```
find $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/dist/*.tar -type f -exec curl --ftp-create-dirs -T {} -u user:pass ftp://my.server.com/uploads/{} \;
```

The last `{}` (in the destination path) causes issues. In TravisCI these files are usually in the path `/home/travis/build/owner/repo/dist`, so adding `{}` to the destination will create these directories as well:

`uploads/home/travis/build/owner/repo/dist/myartifact.tar`

If I remove the `{}`, I end up with a bunch of `FTP 553` errors. Is there some way for me to make `find` just fill the filename instead of the whole path?

Comment: You can use a simple `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Try with `xargs` and parameter substitution :

```
find . -type f | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'curl --ftp-create-dirs -T  $1 -u user:pass ftp://my.server.com/uploads/${1##*/}' \;
```